# iod.lambert method does not work in poliastro 0.14.0 and 0.16.3 in Windows 10 (?)

Tags: python, poliastro

I try to reproduce the "***Analyzing the Parker Solar Probe flybys***" example from the page https://docs.poliastro.space/en/latest/examples/Analyzing%20the%20Parker%20Solar%20Probe%20flybys.html,
but have no success. The call
`v0, v1_pre = iod.lambert(Sun.k, r0, r1, tof.to(u.s))`
(cell #17 in the link above) got the error "*ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)*".
I had tried option like the next
`v0 = iod.lambert(Sun.k, r0, r1, tof.to(u.s))`
and print `v0`. It got the message: "*<generator object lambert at 0x000001BAE85380B0>*".

I had tried *iod.lambert*, *iod.izzo.lambert* and *iod.vallado.lambert*. The last option got error "*AttributeError: module 'poliastro.iod' has no attribute 'vallado'* ".
Jupyter notebook and Python standalone script have the same behavior.
I had tried it with poliastro 0.14.0 and 0.16.3, I reboot Windows after poliastro 0.16.3 install, all with no success.
Python 3.8.2 64 bit.

What I do wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: This belongs in Stack Overflow.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a programming question and should be posted to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to follow the tutorial and encountered the same error as you. Then I tried debugging and got the value in the desired format as shown in the tutorial. Here's what you should do -

1. The value returned by `iod.lambert()` method is a [generator object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6288016/generator-object-is-not-subscriptable-error) which is basically an iterator. We cannot treat it as an array or list, hence indexing won't help. The first step is to convert it into a list. Also, as shown in the tutorial, it does return 2 objects of ['Quantity'](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/units/quantity.html) type but they are within the same generator object, so we will take them in one single output -

```
v = iod.lambert(Sun.k, r0, r1, tof.to(u.s))
m = list(v)
m[0]
```

```
>>> (<Quantity [ 9.59933726, 11.29855172,  2.92449333] km / s>,
 <Quantity [-16.98082099,  23.30752839,   9.13129077] km / s>)
```

2. Now to get v0 from the tutorial, simply index `m` like a normal array -

```
v0 = m[0][0]
v0
```

```
>>> [9.5993373, 11.298552, 2.9244933] km / s
```

```
v1_pre = m[0][1]
v1_pre
```

```
>>> [−16.980821, 23.307528, 9.1312908] km / s
```

Here's the screenshot -
[image: Code Screenshot]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank You very much! All the code of the example works!

Comment: @PeterNazarenko You're welcome! Please mark the answer as accepted if it solved your query.